# What is after RETURN opcode?

Tags: opcode

I compiled a simple smart contract with --bin option (vs --bin-runtime), and looked at the assembly code. I can see that at first, the "setup" code copy all the run-time code with CODECOPY to memory, then RETURN; STOP.

But what happen after RETURN; STOP? I suppose this stops everything, but logically the main code should run next, so I am confused.

To make sense, after RETURN; STOP, EVM should continue to execute the code staying in returned memory, but this does not seem to be explained in Ethereum specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, after the `STOP` nothing is executed. The job of the init code (what you're looking at) is to return the code that will be associated in the future with the newly-created contract address. Once it returns that code, execution is complete. When you subsequently send a transaction to the contract address, that code (that was returned by the init code) will be executed.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that after STOP, a new contract is created, with a new address, and is put on blockchain, so in future, it can be CALL separately? Thanks @smarx !!!

Comment: Yes, that's right.